# How to fix Cyanogenmod 7 hanging on boot animation after NO firmware changes

Tags: cyanogenmod, backup, samsung-nexus-s, boot

I've been using my Google Nexus S with Cyanogenmod 7 for about a year now. Sometimes it rebooted out of the sudden or locked up but all in all worked well.

Today I rebootet the phone und since then it hangs during boot at the animation with the rotating circle.

**How do I fix the phone and get it booting again?**

Unlike many issues I found on the web I did not play with the firmware recently. Unfortunately it's been quite long since the last backup. **I need to dig my data from the device.**

Ways acceptable for me to go:

1. analyzing and fixing the issue
2. getting all my data and install new firmware (while updating to CM10)

**Analyzing the issue**

I installed the Android SDK on my computer (for `adb` and `fastboot`) and successfully ran ClockworkMod Touch Recovery image which proves the the phone hardware is actually fine. Copying files from the `/sdcard` directory worked and I could open a shell but `adb logcat` doesn't work for me. The program keeps "waiting for device".

This is what I had done before:

- phone hung and restarted by removing and reinserting battery
- date and time were set to 2005-01-01 00:00, reset (never had that before)
- installed or updated several apps through F-Droid app "store"

  - installed [And Bible](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=net.bible.android.activity)
  - updated [Barcode Scanner](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.google.zxing.client.android&fdpage=3)
  - maybe updated/installed something else, but can't remember because I browsed through F-Droid quite a long time and read dozens of app descriptions
- status bar crashed, phone still usable but started reboot to get status bar again
- Booom! Phone hangs forever on boot animation

I have the feeling that the Google logo with the open lock which is displayed before the CM boot animation begins stays longer than before. But I am everything but sure.

**Making backup**

As I cannot run any backup apps I have difficulties doing a **reliable** backup. I set up my phone not to sync most of my data to Google. Yes, I missed doing regular backups for some time because I find doing so is not elegantly possible with Android (compared to `tar c /home` or even `mksquashfs` or `rsnapshot` on Linux).

What I need at least in declining order of priority:

1. calendar
2. contacts
3. some app's data
4. saved wireless credentials

What I already got using ClockworkMod Touch Recovery:

- copying `/sdcard` with `adb pull`
- Running backup from the ClockworkMod Touch Recovery menu -- I have no clue what is actually backed up

The ideal way would backup the whole phone so I could install CM10 and retrieve any missing data from the backup or restore the backup to get the current state.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *I installed the SDK and successfully ran Clockwork Recovery image* Clarify this? Do you mean you went into CWM recovery? The status bar crashing.. *installed or updated severall apps through F-Droid app "store"* what apps did you install exactly for this to happen? A Nexus was out since circa December 2010 - so how did it revert back to 2005?

Comment: I guess Android will set the data back to 2005 by default. Probably that not a question of the individual device. But I don't know for sure. I update my question with details you requested.

Comment: And the apps? What sort of apps did you install as well? Might help to post a logcat by plugging in USB and reboot handset and capture the logcat, (*from boot, to full Android environment*) into [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Answer (score 0):

It could even be a corrupted cache file. If you are able to boot into recovery (CWM) you can perform backups, wipe dalvik-cache  and cache and install a current CM7.2. Once in recovery you should be able to mount /data with adb also to run tar, but try the gui.

Comment: Will wiping dalvik-cache, wiping cache or install CM7.2 harm my data? I find loads of forum posts but could not verify that. What portion of my data is contained in `/data`? If I backup `/data` and install CM10 will I be able to use the old data?

Comment: all your data is in.data, nothing in cache. Yes, you can upgrade, though certain apps may need their data cleared.

Answer (score 0):

First wipe the Dalvik cache, then reboot. If that doesn't work, wipe the cache too.

If clearing cache is not working:

- Backup your device's system partition with `adb pull /system`
- Backup the data partition with `adb pull /data`
- Or use `adb backup -apk -shared -all -f something.ab`

After that do a factory reset and restore the backup afterwards.

Comment: I would say save the trouble of using ADB if one already has the custom Recovery installed which can take Nandroid backups.